# Logar com CPF no FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony-2

O FOSUserBundle por padrão se conecta com e-mail ou username e senha.
Porém quero alterar para CPF e senha.

Criei CpfProvider, sobreescrevi algumas classes, porém estou tendo que sobreescrever praticamenteo o FOSUserBundle todo para funcionar.

Comment: Oi Bruno, compartilhe o seu código, existem tantas opções de setup do FOSUserBundle que fica difícil te dar um aconselhamento prático. Na teoria me parece que você poderia herdar de [User](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php) e simplesmente usar o cpf do lugar do `userName` correto? Você faz questão de esconder o mapeamento de `userName` para o CPF? Se não eu deixaria tudo como está e apenas adicionaria um `public function getCpf()` apontando para `userName`.

Comment: Para sobrescrever o `username` e persistí-lo em uma coluna `cpf` use a anotação`AttributeOverride` do doctrine (veja [um exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25582828/664577))